# How to know the column of the start of the function declaration in the source code inspected by getsourcelines?

Tags: python-3.x

`getsourcelines` returns the line where the function is defined.
However, if there are more than one function, like in the example below, it returns both, since it always returns the whole line.

```
import re
from inspect import getsourcelines
def f(f1, f2_is_not_used_now):
    lines = getsourcelines(f1)[0]
    sets = re.findall('(?={)(.+?)(?<=})', lines[0])
    print(sets)


f(lambda x: {x ** 2}, lambda y: {y ** 3})
# output: ['{x ** 2}', '{y ** 3}']
```

How can I get just the code (i.e., only the source code of the `set` of `f1` in this contrived example) related to the inspected function object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no fool-proof way to find the definition of a function object in the source at runtime since function objects exist as bytecodes at runtime, and trying to pinpoint the exact position in the source code in which the function is defined with string parsing would always come with caveats and would break under certain circumstances.

One of the more robust approaches would be to convert the bytecodes of the function object to Python code using a decompiler such as the [uncompyle6](https://pypi.org/project/uncompyle6/) package:

```
from uncompyle6.main import decompile
from io import StringIO

def f(f1, f2_is_not_used_now):
    out = StringIO()
    decompile(bytecode_version=None, co=f1.__code__, out=out)
    print(out.getvalue())


f(lambda x: {x ** 2}, lambda y: {y ** 3})
```

This outputs (sans the comments):

```
return {
 x ** 2}
```

which isn't exactly the original source code that defines the function with a `lambda` call, but would give you its equivalent function converted from the bytecodes.

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/PoisedGleamingField

Comment: A decompiler is exactly what I was looking for, currently

Comment: @olyk note that the trepan3k (and trepan2k) debuggers not only do the decompilation but also make an attempt to show you exactly where in that expression you are. See https://pypi.org/project/trepan3k/#more-exact-location-information and https://rocky.github.io/pycon2018.co/#/